# What can I do next to debug git update hooks not firing?

Tags: git

I'm trying to set up a "server-side" update hook on a git repository but I can't get the "update" hook to fire when a push is received.

For various reasons the clients **must** access the repo via the [Smart-HTTP](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Smart-HTTP) protocol and this seems to be working perfectly for clone/pull/push operation.

According to the docs the update hook should be "run once for each branch the pusher is trying to update" but I can't see any evidence that it's being run at all.

I created a test update script as follows:

```
[root@centos hooks]# ls -al /opt/git/sdl.git/hooks/update
-rwxr-xr-x 1 apache apache 150 Sep 17 16:12 /opt/git/sdl.git/hooks/update
```

For testing purposes the content of the script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$0" > /tmp/update.out
exit 0
```

So running it should create a file in `/tmp` (and it does when I run it as the apache user) but when I do a test push to the repo the push succeeds but no file is created by the hook. I've tried similar things for the pre-receive and post-receive hooks and they also don't seem to be working.

The receiving server (Centos 7) is running git v1.8.3.1 and the pushing client is v1.9.1 so they should be using Smart HTTP (the Apache logs indicate they're using the correct URLs). The permissions look right for the hook scripts so I'm at a bit of a loss for where to look next.

Any help or thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: As which user is your "sever-side" git running? As nobody? I guess you can check it with 'ps ax'

Comment: Since it's using the Smart HTTP protocol (which works as an apache CGI script) it's running as the Apache user "apache". I've tried running the hook script manually as the Apache user and it works as expected. This leads me to believe that it's not being executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [git http-backend](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-http-backend), providing Smart-HTTP-access, enables "hooks [to be] invoked by the git-receive-pack".

Since you're able to access your repositories via your Smart-HTTP-setup i assume that the [git-recieve-package](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-receive-pack) is calling your hook-script. I further assume that this call is done by the `apache`-user (i am still searching for a source for that assumption) and this apache-user might not be able to write to the tmp-directory.

Please assure that the git-daemon-user has the right to write into the `/tmp`-directory or a specific file/directory you created especially for your hook-script.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question I'm using the Smart HTTP protocol so there's no daemon running. Git is executed as an Apache CGI script.

Comment: @simonaldrich - i am very sorry - i misread that part and now fixed my answer, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, it turned out to be something along those lines. Turns out that in Centos 7 the httpd service (apache) is managed by systemd and has PrivateTmp set in its configuration file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service`. This means that what the hooks thought was `/tmp` was actually `/tmp/systemd-private-Y7ktIZ/tmp`

Comment: @simonaldrich - thanks for getting back, i probably should addthat to my answer.